# Одновременное выполнение условия для всех элементов массива

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, visual-c++

Как реализовать обход всех элементов массива внутри условия оператора условия? Нужно сделать так, чтобы одно условие выполнялось одновременно для всех элементов массива, например, если все элементы массива меньше 5  `j++`. 
Хотелось бы что-нибудь в этом роде по смыслу:

```
if(for(int i=0; i<10; i++) arr[i]<5) j++;
```

Comment: Перед циклом заводите переменную и делаете в цикле нужную проверку. Если проверка не прошла - выставляете переменную и выходите из цикла. После цикла ее проверяете.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов можете небольшой пример написать?

Comment: С каким из указанных пунктов именно у вас проблемы?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не понимаю, как я должен осуществлять проверку в цикле, и что значит выставить переменную.

Comment: Проверить в цикле каждый элемент массива можете? Присвоить значение переменной уж точно можете.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов как мне добиться одновременного выполнения условия для всех элементов массива? я не уверен, но мне кажется, Вы больше слов написали, доказывая, что тут все очевидно, чем потребовалось бы на реализацию цикла, раз все так просто

Comment: Одновременного выполнения и не будет, последовательное решает вашу задачу вполне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это очень просто. Ниже показана демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    if ( std::all_of( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), []( int x ) { return x < 5; } ) )
    {
        std::cout << "All elements are less than 5" << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

Или

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    if ( std::all_of( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), std::bind2nd( std::less<int>(), 5 ) ) )
    {
        std::cout << "All elements are less than 5" << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
All elements are less than 5
```

Comment: Мощно! Мне бы так знать `std::`...

Comment: @kff Все впереди.:)

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:

```
bool flag = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    if (arr[i] >= 5) {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
if (flag) {
    // Все элементы меньше 5
}
```

Или так:

```
bool cond(int* arr, size_t N)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if (arr[i] >= 5)
             return false;
    return true;
}

if (cond(arr, 10)) {
    // Все элементы меньше 5
}
```

Можно также использовать лямбды (но код менее понятный):

```
if ([&arr]() {
       for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
           if (arr[i] >= 5)
              return false;
       return true;
     }())
{
    // Все элементы меньше 5
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам сначала нужно вычислить результат, запомнить его в bool, потом заюзать значение в if'е

```
bool less = true;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  if (arr[i] >= 5) {
    less = false;
    break;
  }
}

if (less) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**По конкретному вопросу:**
можно вычислить максимум по массиву и применить условие к нему.